# Pivot Table Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Im new to SQL and trying to make my first pivot table. The code below yields the error `syntax error at or near "PIVOT"`. Any help would be much appreciated! I'm definitely making some basic syntax error but I cant find it for the life of me.

```
SELECT p.SO, p.FR, p.SR, p.JR
FROM
  (SELECT players.year AS year
    FROM benn.college_football_players players) sub

PIVOT
(
  COUNT(sub.year) FOR sub.year IN ([SO], [FR], [SR], [JR])
)
AS p
```

Below is sample data returned from `benn.college_football_players` when the subquery is run on its own

```
year
JR
SO
SO
FR
SR
JR
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use? Syntax varies a lot.

Comment: @juergend, I'm using the MODE Analytics tutorial engine found [here](https://modeanalytics.com/)

Comment: @juergend I believe they say they use SQL Server

Comment: @Matt as I run your query in SQL Server 2012, its working fine without error. It would be better if you provide sample data

Comment: @PrashantPimpale edited to include the first few rows of sample data

Comment: @Matt, where is an error, is it in SQL Server or trying to run on Mode Analytics?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'm running it on the Mode Analytics website, which I believe runs SQL Server on the back-end (possible I'm wrong on that though)

Comment: Have you try to run that query on SQL Server directly instead of mode analytics

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I haven't, I've just been learning through the tutorial, since I don't have data to use of my own. At this point I take it that the error likely has something to do with their end rather than my code above

Answer (score 2):

if your doesn't accept the `PIVOT` command. I would use conditional *aggregate function* use `CASE WHEN` with `COUNT` instead of it.

For example, mysql didn't support *PIVOT* command, but you can use  *aggregate function* do *PIVOT*

```
CREATE TABLE college_football_players(
   Year varchar(50)
);


insert into college_football_players values ('JR');
insert into college_football_players values ('SO');
insert into college_football_players values ('SO');
insert into college_football_players values ('FR');
insert into college_football_players values ('SR');
insert into college_football_players values ('JR');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 'SO' then 1 end) SO,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 'FR' then 1 end) FR,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 'SR' then 1 end) SR,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN year = 'JR' then 1 end) JR
FROM  benn.college_football_players players players
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3486b1/3/0)**:

```
| SO | FR | SR | JR |
|----|----|----|----|
|  2 |  1 |  1 |  2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't the code but that I was running the code on the MODE Analytics SQL tutorial [website](https://modeanalytics.com). The website doesn't seem to accept the `PIVOT` command.